# Mocking in scala generates a java.lang.NoSuchMethodException

Tags: scala, testing, playframework, scalamock

Hey I am trying to test the following class :

```
class Foo {
 def f: Int = 4 + g

 def g: Int = 2
}
```

My test is the following:

```
class FooSpec extends PlaySpec with MockFactory {
  val foo = new Foo()
  "Foo" must {
    "Call function f" in {
        (foo.g _)
        .expects()
        .once()
        .returns(5)

        foo.f must be (9)
     }
   }
}
```

My test is failing saying that :

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Foo.mock$g$0()
java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
...
```

I am not sure to see why ...

I am using scalatest and scalamock :

```
"org.scalatestplus.play" %% "scalatestplus-play" % "1.5.0" % "test"
"org.scalamock" %% "scalamock-scalatest-support" % "3.2.2" % "test"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I see two problems here:

1. You cannot establish mocked answers without actually mocking an object: you create `val foo = new Foo()`, but you have to `mock` this class first: `val foo = mock[Foo]`
2. It looks like ScalaMock doesn't support partially stubbing instances, so you cannot stub method `g` and expect it to get called when you invoke `f` - you'll have to restructurize your code in a way that `Foo.g` is called from another class - wrap it in a delegate perhaps. Or use Mockito - it's not as fancy and does its magic in runtime as opposed to ScalaMock's compile time, but it provides an ability to `callRealMethod()` on a mocked class.

Basically ScalaMock works best when you `mock` or `stub` traits, not classes - their macros don't have to process actual implementations of the methods, and noone would expect them to.

Answer (score 0):

A late answer but since this is the top google result for this error message, just adding another potential issue to look out for: make sure you aren't mocking a `final` method.

This would result in the same error and scalamock doesn't allow that.

If you own the code, just un-`final` the method or work around it in some other way that's acceptable for you.